# Passing class column name as a variable when using caret and train function

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I just started using R and caret to develop a SVM classifier but I am having problems with the train function:

```
mod <- train(Species ~ ., data=dataset, method = "svmLinear", trControl = ctrl)
```

This line works if you use iris dataset, as Species is the class name. But I want the class column name as a variable so I can use it with any dataset, so I changed that line to this:

```
className <- 'Species'
mod <- train(className ~ ., data=dataset, method = "svmLinear", trControl = ctrl)
```

Unfortunately it does not work (error: invalid type (list) for variable 'className'). Does anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could probably plug in `as.formula(paste(className, "~ ."))`

Comment: It works! Thanks! Submit it as an answer so I can mark it!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying to find the whole internet and finally got it here! This deserves the best answer.